# ¿Como se puede sincronizar BD en tiempo real?

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, phpmyadmin

Actualmente estoy desarollando una app la cual debería estar sincronizada la tablet con la BD en tiempo real. ¿Hay alguna manera de lograr eso? Esta app está pensada para una empresa y se supone que cada vez que hayan cambios en la BD, debería estar la tablet sincronizada con la BD.

Mi código en PHP para "exportar" las imagenes es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "SELECT p.progenid, p.progencod, p.progennom,
        pp.PreProPre1, ia.ia_archivo
        FROM productogenerico p 
        INNER JOIN precioproducto pp
            ON p.progenid = pp.proid
        LEFT JOIN imagenarchivo ia
            ON p.progenid = ia.ia_perid";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();

$ruta = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/img/';

while($fila  =$resultado->fetch_array()) {
    $producto["progennom"] = $fila['progennom'];
    $producto["PreProPre1"] = $fila['PreProPre1'];
    $producto["progencod"] = $fila['progencod'];

    if($fila['ia_archivo']) {
        $producto["ImaAsoIma"] = $ruta . $fila['ia_archivo'];
    } else {
        $producto['ImaAsoIma'] = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/default/noimage.png';
    }
    $listado[] = $producto;
}

echo json_encode($listado);
$resultado->close();
?>
```

Mi código en PHP para poder listar las imagenes asociadas a cada producto:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "SELECT p.progenid, p.progencod, p.progennom,
        pp.PreProPre1, ia.ia_archivo
        FROM productogenerico p 
        INNER JOIN precioproducto pp
            ON p.progenid = pp.proid
        LEFT JOIN imagenarchivo ia
            ON p.progenid = ia.ia_perid";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();

$ruta = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/img/';

while($fila  =$resultado->fetch_array()) {
    $producto["progennom"] = $fila['progennom'];
    $producto["PreProPre1"] = $fila['PreProPre1'];
    $producto["progencod"] = $fila['progencod'];

    if($fila['ia_archivo']) {
        $producto["ImaAsoIma"] = $ruta . $fila['ia_archivo'];
    } else {
        $producto['ImaAsoIma'] = 'http://192.168.43.3/WS/default/noimage.png';
    }
$listado[] = $producto;
}

echo json_encode($listado);
$resultado->close();
?>
```

Mi código para la app Android para mostrar las imagenes desde la ruta con Glide es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
private static final String URL_broches = "http://192.168.43.3/WS/listar.php";
ArrayList<Broches> brochesList;
GridView gridView;
EditText editText;
Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    brochesList = new ArrayList<>();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    loadBroches();
}

private void loadBroches(){
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_broches, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("Pruebo1: ", response);
        Broches bro = null;
        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject broche = array.getJSONObject(i);
                bro = new Broches();
                bro.setDescripcion(broche.getString("progennom"));
                bro.setCodigo(broche.getString("progencod"));
                bro.setPrecio(broche.getDouble("PreProPre1"));
                bro.setImage(broche.getString("ImaAsoIma"));
                //bro.setDato(broche.getString("ImaAsoIma"));
                brochesList.add(bro);
            }
            adapter = new Adapter(brochesList, MainActivity.this);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private List<Broches> brochesList;
private List<Broches> brochestemp;
private Context context;

public Adapter(List<Broches> brochesList, Context context) {
    this.brochesList = brochesList;
    this.brochestemp = brochesList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return brochesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return brochesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Broches broches = brochesList.get(position);
    TextView textViewDesc;
    ImageView imageView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNames);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if (brochesList.get(position).getImage() != null) {
        Glide.with(context).load(broches.getImage()).into(imageView);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    }
    textViewDesc.setText(broches.getDescripcion());

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity((new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class).putExtra("broches", brochesList.get(position))));
        }
    });
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null || constraint.length() > 0) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<Broches> filters = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < brochestemp.size(); i++) {
                if (brochestemp.get(i).getDescripcion().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    //Broches bro = new Broches(brochestemp.get(i).getDescripcion(), brochestemp.get(i).getCodigo(), brochestemp.get(i).getCodExterno(), brochestemp.get(i).getPrecio(), brochestemp.get(i).getIdproducto(), brochestemp.get(i).getImagen());
                    Broches bro = new Broches(brochestemp.get(i).getDescripcion(), brochestemp.get(i).getCodigo(), brochestemp.get(i).getPrecio(), brochestemp.get(i).getImage());
                    filters.add(bro);
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = filters.size();
            filterResults.values = filters;

        } else {
            filterResults.count = brochestemp.size();
            filterResults.values = brochestemp;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        brochesList = (List<Broches>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
}

}
```

Comment: desconozco si es posible, pensaría en un intervalo de tiempo para que actualices la información si hay nuevos datos, o alguna bandera o algo que puedas disparar cada que se haga un cambio en la BD para refrescar la tablet

Comment: Si de verdad quieres que sea instantáneo, lo que necesitas es un *websocket*. Basicamente, una conexión que permanece abierta constantemente entre tu app y el backend, y por la que php puede *empujar* los datos a todos los clientes según los recibe.

Comment: usar web socket  o usar firebase que ya esta implementado pero cobra aunque no es mucho.

Comment: Puedes usar Firebase, que haría la sincronización en tiempo real y tiene otras muchas ventajas, hay un pan Blaze que sería de pago  a partir de un determinado consumo. Eso sí, debes tener mucho cuidado en la forma en que programas tu código, porque te puedes llevar un susto en la factura. Yo tengo una App con Firebase con varias decenas de miles de instalaciones y hasta ahora no he tenido que pagar nada en casi dos años funcionando. Si te decides por una BD remota, te recomiendo que revises el apartado *Componentes de Arquitectura* de Android. Tiene todas las herramientas modernas ...

Comment: ... que necesitas para sincronizar tu base de datos remota con una base de datos en cada dispositivo. Los componentes de arquitectura tienen sincronizadores, workers, etc que te permiten hacer todo esto. Pero te advierto que esa parte de Android es algo totalmente nuevo y tiene una curva de aprendizaje considerable para ponerlo en marcha. Te dejo aquí los enlaces de ambas cosas: para [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)  y para los [Componentes de Arquitectura](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture?hl=es&authuser=1) que están compuestos por varias herramientas.

Comment: Parte de los CA es [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?hl=es&authuser=1) que sirve para programar tareas asíncronas y diferibles. Esta API sustituye a varias herramientas que se usaron en el pasado para realizar este tipo de tareas, que es de las más complejas y delicadas de Android porque una sincronización mal programado impactaría mucho en el consumo de batería por ejemplo, lo cual sería un punto negro para tu App.

Comment: @Benito-B para el websocket, ¿necesito instalar algún programa en especifico?

Comment: @A.Cedano eso de Firebase y work manager, ¿es la mejor opción?

Comment: No sería Firebase Y WorkManager, sino Firebase O WorkManager. Si usas Firebase la sincronización en tiempo real la gestiona Firebase, no tienes que hacer nada, solamente poner los listeners adecuados a aquellos documentos cuyos contenidos quieras tener actualizados en tiempo real. Piensa que Firebase se usa mucho en contextos como chats, donde la info cambia constantemente en tiempo real. Firebase te refleja esos cambios en la App en cuanto ocurren. Y hay más ventajas. WorkManager y Componentes de Arquitectura es otro mundo y tienes que programar tú la sincronización.

Comment: "Firebase O WorkManager" no significa que sean incompatibles, sino  que debes elegir uno u otro para resolver **este problema** (si no optas x otra herramienta). En mi App por ejemplo yo uso Firebase para algunas cosas y para otras uso Volley, esperando poder gestionar cierta información en local (en cada dispositivo) para que los usuarios la puedan tener offline. Para todo eso tendré que usar WorkManager, Room y otras herramientas de Componentes de Arquitectura. Otra cosa que olvide decir de Firebase es que persiste cierta cantidad de datos, o sea los puedes ver aunque no haya conexión.

Comment: @A.Cedano Olvidé mencionar que yo en mi app Android estoy usando Volley, ¿Entonces podría usar firebase?

Comment: Firebase podría ser una alternativa interesante con respecto a Volley, por las ventajas que te comenté antes (sincronización en tiempo real, disponibilidad off-line, etc) y otras, como rapidez y menos riesgo de que el contenido no esté disponible si tu servidor remoto está caido. Pero hay algo que no dije: Firebase está basado en No-SQL, significa que en Firebase los datos se estructuran de un modo totalmente distinto a como se trabaja en las bases de datos relacionales. Ese es un punto delicado, si estructuras mal los datos vas a tener problemas y si contratas un plan Blaze por ejemplo ...

Comment: ... y lo usas en una App con varios cientos de miles de usuarios, si tienes una estructura mal montada o un código mal programado, te puedes llevar una sorpresa en la factura. Por poner un ejemplo, Firebase podría computar por lectura de documentos, imagina que tienes cientos o miles de documentos relacionados con otros y escribes mal una consulta en la cual para encontrar un dato, esa consulta mal escrita lee todos los documentos de una colección, pues cada vez que los miles de usuarios de la App haga esa consulta se estarán leyendo cientos o miles de documentos sin necesidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano Probé con Firebase, pero no me está mostrando el listado allí, no entiendo cual podría ser el problema

Comment: Eso sería tema para una nueva pregunta donde muestres tu código basado en Firebase, el resultado de los Logs con las depuraciones que has hecho, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya hice una nueva pregunta sobre este problema, cuyo enlace es este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/444505/no-me-aparece-el-listado-en-firebase